# d3.pack Multiple hierarchies with a single JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a JSON file which I need to use to generate three different hierarchy visualisations using d3.pack.

The JSON file contains information for eventA (1 or 0) and eventB (1 or 0). Each leaf also has a unique ID.

I need to show hierarchies as follows.
First hierarchy : Total population (if there are 10000 elements, show all 10000).
Second hierarchy : eventA (so group all the 1s and all the 0s)
Third hierarchy : eventB, subdivided by eventA values.

At the moment, I'm using three different multidimensional JSON files, which is not very efficient, and simply erasing the old data and creating new ones. However, the transitions are important for what I need to do, so it doesn't quiet cut it.

Does anyone have any clue on how I can achieve this?

I'm not looking for code, just suggestions on how I can approach the problem.

Here is an example of what the JSON data looks like.

```
{
  "name":"Total",
  "children":[
    {
      "name":"POPULATION (n=20)",
      "children":[
        {
          "id":1,
          "eventA":1,
          "eventB":1,
          "size":50
        },
        {
          "id":2,
          "eventA":1,
          "eventB":1,
          "size":49
        },
        {
          "id":3,
          "eventA":1,
          "eventB":1,
          "size":48
        },
        {
          "id":4,
          "eventA":1,
          "eventB":1,
          "size":47
        },
        {
          "id":5,
          "eventA":1,
          "eventB":0,
          "size":46
        },
        {
          "id":6,
          "eventA":0,
          "eventB":1,
          "size":45
        },
        {
          "id":7,
          "eventA":0,
          "eventB":1,
          "size":44
        },
        {
          "id":8,
          "eventA":0,
          "eventB":1,
          "size":43
        },
        {
          "id":9,
          "eventA":0,
          "eventB":1,
          "size":42
        },
        {
          "id":10,
          "eventA":0,
          "eventB":0,
          "size":41
        },
        {
          "id":11,
          "eventA":0,
          "eventB":0,
          "size":40
        },
        {
          "id":12,
          "eventA":0,
          "eventB":0,
          "size":39
        },
        {
          "id":13,
          "eventA":0,
          "eventB":0,
          "size":38
        },
        {
          "id":14,
          "eventA":0,
          "eventB":0,
          "size":37
        },
        {
          "id":15,
          "eventA":0,
          "eventB":0,
          "size":36
        },
        {
          "id":16,
          "eventA":0,
          "eventB":0,
          "size":35
        },
        {
          "id":17,
          "eventA":0,
          "eventB":0,
          "size":34
        },
        {
          "id":18,
          "eventA":0,
          "eventB":0,
          "size":33
        },
        {
          "id":19,
          "eventA":0,
          "eventB":0,
          "size":32
        },
        {
          "id":20,
          "eventA":0,
          "eventB":0,
          "size":31
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know about [`d3.nest`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#nest)? That's probably what you want to use for this. In that case, you would load the data as a flat array, like

```
var flatData = [
  {
    "name1": "Total",
    "name2": "POPULATION (n=20)",
    "id": 1,
    "eventA": 1,
    "eventB": 1,
    "size": 50
  },
  {
    "name1": "Total",
    "name2": "POPULATION (n=20)",
    "id": 2,
    "eventA": 1,
    "eventB": 0,
    "size": 49
  },
  {
    "name1": "Total",
    "name2": "POPULATION (n=20)",
    "id": 3,
    "eventA": 0,
    "eventB": 1,
    "size": 48
  },
  ...
]
```

(Note, I used `name1` and `name2` because I didn't know what to meaningfully call those things).

From there, to turn it into the grouping you posted:

```
d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.name1 })
  .key(function(d) { return d.name2 })
  .entries(dataset)
```

And to get it into the 2nd of the 3 grouping you described (ie by the value of `eventA`):

```
d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.eventA })
  .entries(dataset)
```

And to get it into the 3rd grouping you described (ie by the value of `eventB`, **then by** `eventA`):

```
d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.eventB })
  .key(function(d) { return d.eventA })
  .entries(dataset)
```

The results you get will be hierarchically similar to what you're showing with `name` and `children`, except that `d3.nest` will call them `key` and `values`, respectively. It's slightly inconvenient, because I believe d3's hierarchical layouts (including pack) use `key` and `children`. But you can easily re-map the keys after the nest operation.

The `d3.nest` object also accepts a `rollup` function where you can tell it (how) to transform all the values in the lowest-level group into a single values. For example, this would sum all thee sizes for a given `eventA` group value:

```
d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.eventA; })
  .rollup(function(values) { return d3.sum(values, function(d) { return d.size; }) })
  .entries(dataset);
```

Comment: Fantastic! I haven't tried it yet, but this should indeed solve my problem. I've been racking my brain for two days trying to figure this out... Thank you!

Comment: So, your solution is perfect, thank you very very much.

That said, for the problem with the .nest, I simply modified the d3.v3.min.js code and changed the "key" and "value" to "name" and "children under the .nest() function, insted of remapping them after calling the operation. Everything now works like a charm!

Comment: @GuillaumeBolduc great, glad it worked out. I gotta say though, it's not totally a great idea to modify the d3 source — especially for something that can be easily worked-around. In fact, now that I know you're using version 3, you can tell the pack layout how to look for `d.values` instead of `d.children`, so you wouldn't even need to re-map the data. Modifying the source means that unless you git commit your modified d3 version (as opposed to using npm or bower), if you ever reinstall or upgrade d3 version, your code will break unless you modify the d3 source again.

Comment: This is how you tell pack layout to use `d.values`: https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Pack-Layout.md#children

Comment: Great, thank you very much, I fixed it accordingly :)